# Is there anyway to have multi line spanning string without using +

Tags: javascript

I have a large html string that I am populating with data and using in an innerHTML...

I want to make a string like this:

```
var str = '<div>
    <div></div>
    </div>';
```

Instead of like this:

```
var str = '<div>'
    +'<div></div>'
    +'</div>';
```

Is there a way?

Comment: I get this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A backslash at the end of the line will indicate that the line is continuing to the next:

```
var str = '<div>\
    <div></div>\
    </div>';
```

Comment: Make sure there's no whitespace after the slash. That'll getcha every time.

Answer (score 1):

While probably not what you are looking for, you can also do something like this:

```
var str=[];
str.push('<div>');
str.push('<div></div>');
str.push('</div>');
html = str.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backslash..

```
var str = 'bla\
   foo\
    bar';
```

You can join it:

```
var str = ['foo',
'bar',
'baz'].join('')
```

You can push and then join it:

```
var a = [];
a.push('<div>');
a.push('blah');
a.join('')
```